# jQuery fade in fade out textarea and button over blur(function) of text area?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery code for a 'textarea' and 'submit' button to fade in when 'add' button is clicked and fade out when clicked else where or 'submit' button.

when 'submit' and 'textarea' fades in 'add' button disappears ANS vice versa.

Everything works fine except I am being forced to click "add" button twice or thrice to execute the function 
AND
I would like to have the "textarea" auto focused.

My script as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$().ready = function() {
    $('#textarea').hide();
$('#submit').hide();
$("#add").click(function() {
$('#add').hide();
$('#textarea').fadeIn('slow').focus();
$('#submit').fadeIn('slow').focus();
});
$('#textarea').blur(function(){
$('#textarea').hide();
$('#submit').hide();
$('#add').fadeIn('slow'); 
});        
}();
});//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="add" id="add" />
<input type="text" id="textarea" />
<input type="submit" value=" submit" id="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Any Suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: for the text area to get focused you can use $('#text').focus()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need change "$('#submit').fadeIn('slow').focus();" to "$('#submit').fadeIn('slow');".

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @xh-2016 Can you take a look on this one man... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330887/slide-up-slide-down-is-not-working-for-selected-table-rows-from-db

Answer (score 0):

### This is what you have to do

You dont need this ***$(window).load(function(){})*** because has almost the same function as ***$(window).load(function(){})***

Use ***document.ready()*** to start the Script

And use the ***onclick()*** event to hide and display the specific element

To Hide elements you can use ***selector.style.display = "none"*** or ***remove()***  But in this case you have to use ***style.display ="none"*** because ***remove()*** will remove the element.  use  to display it use ***fadeIn()*** and insert "slow" like this ***fadein('slow')*** for the slow effect and you only need one ***focus()*** for one even

***Example Like This***

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="add" id="add" />
    <input type="text" id="textarea" />
    <input type="submit" value=" submit" id="submit" />
    <p id="p" style="display:none;">Here You Go !</p>
</body>
</html>
```

***Js***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var add = document.getElementById('add');
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    var text = document.getElementById('textarea');
    var p = document.getElementById('p');

    text.style.display = "none";
    submit.style.display = "none";

    add.onclick = function(){
        $(p).fadeIn();
        $(text).fadeIn('slow').focus();
        $(submit).fadeIn('slow');
        add.style.display = "none";
    }
    submit.onclick = function(){
        $(p).fadeOut();
        $(text).fadeOut();
        $(submit).fadeOut();
        $(add).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

***Tested***